# How to set non color to node in shading in aces color space?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, color-management

[image]

Can`t find non color setting to roughness, normal map textures in aces color space.

Comment: ACES has some shitty labels. Utility - Raw or Role - Data.

Comment: lol ACES doesn't have shitty labels. Those are industry standard labels that Blender should have adopted. They are aligned between many disciplines. Utility-Raw is raw data, aka no color conversions applied, aka what blender refers to as Non-Color.